# Configuring redirection in Flask

Tags: python, flask, redirect, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi am pretty much new to Flask. I am creating a blog where i am scraping some articles from other sites and few articles from database (MySQL) as well.
my URL:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/https://bitcoinist.com/beware-bullish-bitcoin-case-could-be-due-to-cftc-scramble/

is returning

> 404 not found error.

I want to redirect this to the following URL:

https://bitcoinist.com/beware-bullish-bitcoin-case-could-be-due-to-cftc-scramble/

I can not hardcode this URL as it is coming from slug in database and keeps changing. How to redirect it using error handler or any other way?

This is the code below which is fetching the blog content from database. The URL I want to redirect is stored in database as slug. The blog which I am uploading in database are working fine. Only want to configure redirection for external blogs or news articles.

For external URL which are stored as slug it returns 404:
the URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/https://bitcoinist.com/beware-bullish-bitcoin-case-could-be-due-to-cftc-scramble/

and want to redirect it to:
https://bitcoinist.com/beware-bullish-bitcoin-case-could-be-due-to-cftc-scramble/

```
@app.route('/post/<string:post_slug>', methods=['GET'])
def post_route(post_slug):
        post = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=post_slug).first()
        return render_template('post.html', params=params, post=post)
```

sorry I am new to SO and not able to put my query the way it supposed to.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to include your code in your post.

Comment: You can register a route for `/post/<url>`, then use `url` to look up the entry in the database before redirecting to the correct URL?

Comment: @MatsLindh has the solution

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution and it worked(at least for now).
the url which was returning 404 error I split it and took the url at which it supposed to redirect using error handler.
Below is the code.

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def go_to(url):
    url = str(str(request.path).split('/post/')[1])
    return redirect(url)
```

so the above code is returning the remainig url after post/. i.e.
(https://bitcoinist.com/beware-bullish-bitcoin-case-could-be-due-to-cftc-scramble/) (check question for reference)